# .load a php page every 3 seconds with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Right now I have this jquery:

```
$(".updatetwo").click(function () {
$('div.result').load('permissions.php);
});
```

I wanted to know, how could I .load the php every 3 seconds instead of on click?

Comment: Maybe you want to load a portion of a page. Hope you have a good explanation for hole page load, instead of a portion of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var handler= window.setInterval(function(){
    jQuery('div.result').load('permissions.php');
},3000);
```

if you plan to stop loading data, you can clear the handler

```
window.clearInterval(handler);
```

--

`window.setInterval(code,delay)`, `setInterval` executes any `code` after mentioned  `delay` in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('div.result').load('permissions.php');
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('div.result').load('permissions.php');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `setInterval`, is using `setTimeout` in a tail recursive fashion. This way, your function will be called approximately<sup>*</sup> 3000 ms after the previous call.

```
(function loadPermissions() {
    jQuery('div.result').load('permissions.php');
    setTimeout(loadPermissions, 3000);
})();
```

<sup>*</sup> I say approximately, since neither `setInterval` or `setTimeout` are an exact science. The delay will be as close as possible to the set delay, but because the browser takes care of drawing and executing scripts in a blocking fashion, you can't set your clock based on this.